# R base function to sort vector of strings based on length

Tags: r, sorting, string-length

I was wondering if there is an already made function in R base package that can sort a vector of strings taking into consideration the length of each element and then of course the lexicographical order. 
For instance after a *sort* call on some vector holding age groups you would have:

```
v <- c("00-04", "05-09", "10-14", "100-104", "105-109", "110-114", "15-19", "20-24"..etc)
```

whereas I would like to have:

```
v <- c("00-04", "05-09", "10-14", "15-19", "20-24"..etc.. "100-104", "105-109", "110-114")
```

Comment: `v[order(nchar(v))]`?

Comment: Yup. Thank you. That did the trick and does not require any other library :]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simply with `order` :

```
v[order(nchar(v), v)]

## [1] "00-04"   "05-09"   "10-14"   "15-19"   "20-24"   "100-104" "105-109" "110-114"
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah. I will accept this as the "official" answer even though Ananda was the first to provide the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Marius, no problem. I was on my phone so I couldn't verify my answer, and I don't like posting answers that I don't know work. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Not in R base, but this splits the strings in numeric and character parts and sorts appropriately:

```
v <- c("00-04", "05-09", "10-14", "100-104", "105-109", "110-114", "15-19", "20-24")
library(gtools)
mixedsort(v)
#[1] "00-04"   "05-09"   "10-14"   "15-19"   "20-24"   "100-104" "105-109" "110-114"
```

You can always copy the code of the `mixedorder` function defined in the gtools package if you don't want to load/depend on it.

Comment: I chose the answer Ananda gave as it does not need another library. Thank you for your answer also.